# How to re scale information of an image coordinates to work on a scaled version of similar image

Tags: python, image, opencv, yolo

I used yolov3 to detect objects in a frame of size `416x416`. I used that bounding box information to draw boxes on that `416x416` image.

But since the picture is so small, i can not see it properly, so i used the same frame which has dims `1920x1080`. I want to scale the bounding box information and x,y cordinates such that it scales to the high dim picture but i am not able to correct scale it.

clearly the information is way off.

Note! Before passing the frame, i resize the frames from 1920,1080 to 416,416 using this method

```
def letterbox_resize(img, size=(resized_image_size,resized_image_size), padColor=0):

    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    sh, sw = size

    # interpolation method
    if h > sh or w > sw: # shrinking image
        interp = cv2.INTER_AREA
    else: # stretching image
        interp = cv2.INTER_CUBIC

    # aspect ratio of image
    aspect = w/h  # if on Python 2, you might need to cast as a float: float(w)/h

    # compute scaling and pad sizing
    if aspect > 1: # horizontal image
        new_w = sw
        new_h = np.round(new_w/aspect).astype(int)
        pad_vert = (sh-new_h)/2
        pad_top, pad_bot = np.floor(pad_vert).astype(int), np.ceil(pad_vert).astype(int)
        pad_left, pad_right = 0, 0
    elif aspect < 1: # vertical image
        new_h = sh
        new_w = np.round(new_h*aspect).astype(int)
        pad_horz = (sw-new_w)/2
        pad_left, pad_right = np.floor(pad_horz).astype(int), np.ceil(pad_horz).astype(int)
        pad_top, pad_bot = 0, 0
    else: # square image
        new_h, new_w = sh, sw
        pad_left, pad_right, pad_top, pad_bot = 0, 0, 0, 0

    # set pad color
    if len(img.shape) is 3 and not isinstance(padColor, (list, tuple, np.ndarray)): # color image but only one color provided
        padColor = [padColor]*3

    # scale and pad
    scaled_img = cv2.resize(img, (new_w, new_h), interpolation=interp)
    scaled_img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(scaled_img, pad_top, pad_bot, pad_left, pad_right, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=padColor)

    return scaled_img
```

If someone help me in writing a script which will rescale the x,y,w,h info of the yolo predictions so that i can correctly draw accurate boxes on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your re-scaling process doesn't take into account the zero padded area on the top. Remove the top zero pads before multiplying with the scale ratio and you should be able to get the proper result.

Here is an example code for all 3 cases where bounding box is the points that corresponds to the result from YOLO.

```
def boundBox_restore(boundingbox, ori_size=(ori_image_width,ori_image_height), resized_size=(resized_image_size,resized_image_size)):

    h, w = ori_size
    sh, sw = resized_size

    scale_ratio =  w / sw

    ox,oy,ow,oh = boundingbox

    # aspect ratio of image
    aspect = w/h  # if on Python 2, you might need to cast as a float: float(w)/h

    # compute scaling and pad sizing
    if aspect > 1: # horizontal image
        new_w = sw
        new_h = np.round(new_w/aspect).astype(int)
        pad_vert = (sh-new_h)/2
        pad_top, pad_bot = np.floor(pad_vert).astype(int), np.ceil(pad_vert).astype(int)
        pad_left, pad_right = 0, 0
    elif aspect < 1: # vertical image
        new_h = sh
        new_w = np.round(new_h*aspect).astype(int)
        pad_horz = (sw-new_w)/2
        pad_left, pad_right = np.floor(pad_horz).astype(int), np.ceil(pad_horz).astype(int)
        pad_top, pad_bot = 0, 0
    else: # square image
        new_h, new_w = sh, sw
        pad_left, pad_right, pad_top, pad_bot = 0, 0, 0, 0


    # remove pad
    ox = ox - pad_left
    oy = oy - pad_top

    # rescale
    ox = ox * scale_ratio
    oy = oy * scale_ratio
    ow = ow * scale_ratio
    oh = oh * scale_ratio


    return (ox,oy,oh,ow)
```